# Bounce rate nearly 100% in Safari AND Firefox?

Tags: javascript, browsers, firefox, safari, bounce-rate

Our website has a bounce rate of nearly 100% in both Firefox and Safari, and around ~40% in all other browsers. The bounces span all versions of each browser and both operating systems. I cannot recreate any error in either browser on any of my computers, and I'm not getting any php errors on my server. Firebug isn't throwing any javascript errors.

The most prevalent google result for Safari is that top sites is skewing the bounce rate. But this seems extreme, and the addition of firefox pretty much rules it out. This one really has me confused. I've been googling for weeks to no avail.

Our home page bounce rate is very low across all browsers. Any insight whatsoever, including what types of errors would cause safari and firefox to respond identically to would be greatly appreciated. (the offending landing page is http://www.livesportstickets.com/wrestling/wwe-tickets.php)

Comment: that's absurd. i'm a webmaster asking a webmaster question, how is that off topic?

Comment: Disagree that question is unlikely to help anyone else. Certainly possible that whatever is causing this site to have significantly different bounce rates from different users could also happen to someone else. Also possible that it couldn't, but we can't tell before answers are provided.

Comment: please clarify: does the entire site have a near 100% bounce rate or just one page? And about how many hits on this page/site are in the sample we're talking about?

Comment: It seems to be only the landing pages that are being affected. Users that land on the home page are only bouncing around ~10%.

Comment: The question was closed because in its current form it's unlikely to help anyone else, this doesn't necessary mean it can't be rescued and made more generic that is likely going to help more people, please ensure you read the FAQ and in future please use the META for complaining about closure reasons. Additionally troubleshooting questions can be asked on our chat, I have left what I believe could be the problem on there.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to check in http://browsershots.org/ . take all browser test  with wide range of versions. try to find a Mozilla browser  version that you facing problem. Learn the look an feel . if not check for any error in the coding,like jquery . I heard some time back there was some problem in Google Analytic with respect Firefox regarding this same bounce rate ( some BOT issues) .

Comment: I've checked out browsershots. I find that site to be a bit hard to use when dissecting errors because a lot of their browsers tend to throw errors even when nothing is wrong. The only error I could seems to produce in browsershots was a 'The browser has encountered an error and must close' error, but again I'm not sure if it my an issue on their end or mine.